# PHP simple HTML Dom parser, how parse Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, simple-html-dom

Well here we go,

Is there a way to parse Javascript with PHP simple HTML Dom parser? I want to parse web content generated by Javascript without a direct way to parse images ...etc because they are created after the Javascript generates it.

Here is the web source code: view-source:http://www.pcbox.com/discos-duros_serial-ata-2---sata2_040507.aspx?ch=00000205110002000212031201fa80376ded0f8f1a2a036267416fe20#productos

and the web: http://www.pcbox.com/discos-duros_serial-ata-2---sata2_040507.aspx?ch=00000205110002000212031201fa80376ded0f8f1a2a036267416fe20#productos

If you check the source the images ...etc are generated by JavaScript so I can't directly parse them. Is there a parser for PHP that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only parse the DOM as it exists. You would need an entire javascript engine integrated into the parser in order to do that. I suppose it could potentially be done with other external tools (i.e. handing off to node.js or something and then gettign the final DOM back fro parsing by php) but thats a whole lot of complication.

One could also attempt to make a js analyzer for a specific set of use cases but this is bound to be error prone expecially if the html in question is coming from a site you dont control.